# Error creating a package version

Tags: salesforcedx, unmanaged-package

I get an error while trying to create a package version with this command

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p MySalesforcePackage -d force-app -k MyPassWord --wait 10 -v DevHub
```

This is the arror. It was created as an Unmanaged Package

```
ERROR:  MyConnectedAppApiName: Installing an app (MyConnectedAppApiName) that has been deleted.
```

This is the connected App inside the folder force-app/main/defult/connectedApps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConnectedApp xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<contactEmail>fabrizio@mysite.com</contactEmail>
<description>Connected App</description>
<label>My App</label>
<oauthConfig>
    <callbackUrl>https://myappsite.com/salesforce/setup</callbackUrl>
    <scopes>Full</scopes>
    <scopes>RefreshToken</scopes>
</oauthConfig>
</ConnectedApp>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So i found out what the problem is Connected Apps are not available in [Unmanaged Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_unmanaged_components.htm), they are available in managed Packages.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to add connected app in unlocked package. I am getting same error when creating unlocked package.

Comment: An unlocked package without a namespace is similar to the old style of unmanaged package. So you will have the same problem @lambad

Answer (score 2):

To reconfirm after spending way too many hours researching: No

Page 40 from "Package and Distribute Your Apps" spring 19
Connected Apps
• Connected apps can be added to managed packages, only. Connected apps are not supported for unmanaged packages.