# sfdx create package version connected app error

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, connected-apps

I'm trying to create a managed package with a connected app. I have created the connected app in a scratch org and pulled it into source control (without the consumer key). After creating a package using `force:package:create -t Managed`, I try to create a package version:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p "App Name" -k password -w 5
```

Then following error comes up:

```
ERROR running force:package:version:create:  Connected_App: Installing an app (Connected_App) that has been deleted.
```

If I remove the connected app metadata file from source control, everything works fine. I've found [a similar issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251055/error-creating-a-package-version) but it seemed to because they were using an unmanaged package.